# MS SQL server error while making a procedure

Tags: sql-server, database, autocomplete, procedure

I simply want to get a procedure which displays names which start with letters Up (I'm trying to make an Auto complete for ASP.NET)

```
select * from Diagnose

Create proc spGetNames 'Up'
@term nvarchar (50)
as
Begin
    Select Name
    from Diagnose
    where Name like @term + '%'
End
```

But this error keeps poping out:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure spGetNames, Line 3 [Batch Start Line 0]
Incorrect syntax near 'Up'.
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Procedure spGetNames, Line 9 [Batch Start Line 0]
Must declare the scalar variable "@term".
```

On youtube people did the same as me and it worked for them:
[image]

Any tips would be great :)

Comment: Read the error message : ```Create proc spGetNames 'Up'``` -> What this ```'Up' ``` is doing here ? You're creating a procedure, not calling it

Comment: Im trying to lookup the element that I'm looking in the table, my table consists of nvarchar Name and I'm looking up word that's starts with 'up'

Comment: @OlivierDepriester  edited how other people did it and it worked for them

Comment: On your printscreen from the youtube demo, the part `spGetStudentNames 'M'` is highlighted.  When pressing F5 only this part is executed. But i'm sure that when the youtuber created the stored procedure the `'M'` was not there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Remove 'Up' when you create Procedure

   Create proc spGetNames 
   @term nvarchar (50)
   as
   Begin
       Select Name  
       from Diagnose 
       where Name like @term + '%' 
   End
2. Execute your procedure like following

   exec spGetNames 'Up'